# Disable mouse wheel inside of ul{position:fixed}

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am using wordpress site. I created menu bar, inside of sub-menu, used `position:fixed` element. Anybody tell me how can i disable mousewheel inside of that sub-menu. That means i don't want page scroll inside of that sub-menu.

Please anyone help me.

Comment: better solution submenu open, body apply css position:fixed & overflow:hidden

Comment: Depending on what the restrictions are, you could always use JavaScript to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS property `overflow: hidden;` which specifies what happens if content overflows an element's box.

Using `overflow: hidden;` allow you to do not show up the scroll bar and so do not allowing scrolling at all including mouse weal.

Here below a very generic example, please consider to add your real markup in your question for a fix on your real app code.

https://jsfiddle.net/bxohL8tt/2/

```
#sub-menu{
  width:250px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color:red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the element that is scrolling on mouse-wheel event is the body, or even some other element, you can use JavaScript to prevent it from scrolling while your menu has "focus" like this:

```
var menuBar = document.getElementById('menuBar');

menuBar.onmouseover = function()
{
    document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
};

menuBar.onmouseout = function()
{
    document.body.style.overflow = 'auto';
};
```

Add the above inside a `<script>` element at the end of your main HTML source-code and it should work.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by the following code:

```
$("sub-menu-selector").bind("wheel mousewheel", function() {
    return false;
});
```

For example: (The example shows the disabling on the menu but it's just the same)

```js
$(".menu").bind("wheel mousewheel", function() {
  return false;
});
```

```css
body {
  margin:0;  
}

.menu {
  background:black;
  color:#fff;
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  padding:15px;
}

.content {
  height:1500px;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  Menu
</div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

Comment: but it only works with chrome only.I want firebox ,safari,IE also

Comment: You are right. I was updated my answer according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274326/firefoxjquery-mousewheel-scroll-event-bug#23015652) and it's seem that it's working.